# Board recommendations for GPRS/GSM for 'on the go'

Tags: shields, gsm, gps

I have been tasked to find a way of communicating to a webservice from my microcontroller - yay!

With little-no real grasp on sms/etc (due to not ever 'using' it before), it appears that my knowledge of GPRS is, well, none existent.

So, I've come here in hope that someone could tell me if there is such a way for a microcontroller to 'send data out' though, well, a 'sim card' via an sms message.

---

This has left me a little lost If i'm honest.

My project involves 'tracking' a vehicle (still working on finding a GPS module for that), and then sending the coordinates back to HQ at hourly intervals (via text message).

So, My obvious question is this: *What GPRS sim card module will allow me to do this?*

I read [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/which-shield-to-use-for-gprs), although the accepted answer there for a chip requires external power, and so is of no 'true' use to me as the whole unit needs to be powered and left 'unattended' for long hours at a time.

seeing as I also need to 'monitor current location' of the board, I am also in need to obtain a GPS location.

I was thinking that mobile phones have both of these cababilitys - is this done with a 'sim card module', or is there a way of 'one module does both - send an sms AND can also gain current GPS location'?

---

Sorry if this is too broad, but I'm certainly not 'gifted' in knowing too much about these technologies (esp. when all these acronyms use similar letters).

Any advice / input here would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project that have the same idea that yours.

I used Ublox NEO-6M GPS Module for GPS tracking, the module cost in a range from $6 to $13 USD(it depends from where the seller ships, china o USA) in EBAY. You can connect it via UART.

For the internet I used a SIM800L V2.0 5V Wireless GSM GPRS MODULE, you can buy it from EBAY too, it cost no more than $10.00 USD, and you can connect to internet or send SMS using AT commands.

I used a combination of arduino and Raspberry pi zero, also I send the GPS data to a webserver (I pay 5dllr/month for a VPS) and then I can track using google maps.

Thats the basic information, you can use it to start working.